# Adaptar GRID a Contenedor FIJO

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

como estan?
Estoy realizando un trabajo con una GRID de Bootstrap y necesitaría definir "contenedores" de X tamaño fijo, y que si el GRID es mas grande a ese contenedor. Se adapte automaticamente.
¿Me explico? :)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<style>
        .contenedor1{
            max-height: 150px !important;
            max-width: 600px !important;
            border: solid 1px black;
            margin: auto;
            //overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedor1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 border">Column</div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 border">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis ullam odio deserunt, expedita ratione est temporibus quae soluta porro molestias nobis, facere natus. Facilis, laboriosam sed provident ab modi vero!</div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 border">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia maiores reprehenderit beatae atque, sapiente animi amet autem excepturi, quis corrupti, minima obcaecati odio quasi officia. Expedita tenetur laboriosam ea nobis.</div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Buen día, Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si adjuntas tu código en la descriptción de tu pregunt con lo que has intentado hasta el momento nos ayudas mejor a conseguir solución a tu inquietud

Comment: @Huskie agregado :)

Comment: A que te refieres con que se adapte automáticamente? Podrías ser más especifico?

Comment: Supongo que quiere decir que se muestre solo lo que cabe y lo demas se vea con un scroll. Dado que el contenedor lo quiere de un tamaño fijo. Es lo que entiendo yo.

Comment: @Huskie lo que necesito es que si el "contenido" de las 3 tablas del GRID, abarcan un tamaño superior a la del "Contenedor1". Las tablas se redimencionen automaticamente para que entren las 3 visibles en el contenedor. Sin scroll, porque esto se imprime en papel.

Comment: Pero si no colocarás scroll y además el contenedor tiene ancho y alto predeterminado lo único que se me ocurre de momento es cambio de página porque imagino la impresión será en pdf cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo es más facil si le pones flexbox al contenedor y porcentajes a las cajas sin usar bootstrap. solo tienes que tener en cuenta la cantidad de cajas que quieres tener dentro del contenedor y dividir su 100% de ancho entre esas cajas Ejem: si son 6, width:33% y 50% height.

```
        .contenedor1{
            max-height: 150px !important;
            max-width: 600px !important;
            border: solid 1px black;
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-contend: center;
            //overflow: hidden;
        }
        div{
         width:50%;
         height:50%;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
}
```